# pass value to Redirect in mvc5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Welcome(FormCollection frm)
    {         

        frm["parameter1"] = "Welcome1";
        frm["parameter2"] = "Welcome2";
        frm["parameter3"] = "Welcome3";
        frm["parameter4"] = "Welcome4";
        return Redirect("https://www.example.com");
    }
```

Question :

I want to pass FormCollection Object when redirect to separate domain like "https://www.example.com"

Is this possible or not ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: if you are sending all your formcollection values to another domain why not directly submit from html instead of first sending form values to your server then sending to another domain.

Comment: If you want to target another domain/server with specific URL, use `HttpWebRequest` with `WebRequest.Create` & specify `ContentType`, `Method` & `ContentLength`.

Comment: @ Bhuban Shrestha  I am doing same thing but I want to know is it possible because i want to hide some fields which I donot want print on html page

Comment: @ Tetsuya Yamamoto Please give small demo code which help to write code

Comment: You could pass those as parameters using query string. Just build the url properly like `https://www.example.com/?param1=Welcome1&param2=Welcome2`

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the id as part of the routeValues parameter of the RedirectToAction() method.

return RedirectToAction("Action", new { id = 20 });

Answer (score 0):

Redirecting is HTTPGET request type, but you want to send data with your request, so it isn't redirecting process, you can use `HttpClient` class for posting data, refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015324/http-request-with-post) question.